# Filter values from Rest Api

Tags: angularjs, rest

On Angular I have the following REST API call to get all genders:

```
GetGenderList: function () {
  return $http.get('api/genders');
}
```

This returns four genders:

```
0 - Unknown  
1 - Male  
2 - Female  
9 - NotApplicable
```

Now I would like to get a Gender short list that would return only:

```
1 - Male  
2 - Female
```

How would you create the rest api? Something like:

```
GetGenderList: function () {
  return $http.get('api/genders-short-list');
}
```

Or would you pass the parameters of the genders wanted?

Maybe passing parameters would be a better option because I might want other genders ...

**NOTE:**
I am using gender as an example of similar but with more data scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We pass parameters to our service that tell us what records we want back.  I would go that route.  I would not create a new endpoint for this.

Below you would send in your filter by modifying the value of the params property.  I'm sending 'shortList', but you could send in null to get the entire list back:

```
$http({
    url: 'api/genders', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {filter: 'shortList'}
 });
```

If you want to send in id's you could do it like this:

```
var ids = [0,1,2];

$http({
    url: 'api/genders', 
    method: "GET",
    params: {id: ids}
 });
```

Doing the above will make your call look like this:

```
/api/genders?id=0&id=1&id=2
```

You can also filter the results inside your app if that is a better solution.

Here's the docs for $http get: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Comment: I can pass the names of the genders or the ids. How would I configure the call in Angular?

Comment: You could send in either.  I would send in Id's though.  See my updated answer.